# Book about kid with superpowers who meets other kids with superpowers

Tags: story-identification

- Can't remember is the main character is male or female
- The protagonist is held against his will by an organization who has other kids with superpowers as well.
- The organization gives the kids with superpowers gifts as incentives. The organization is rich.
- In one part, the kids' handlers take them to see a dirt bike show, and one of the kids use their powers to cause the rider to fall and injure himself.